# get user's name and pic from id - graph API iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a game which is saving opponents ID. So I wanted to know how can I get user's name and and profile pic from the id here is what goes in for the parameter in

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"_______" andDelegate:self];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you get the facebook ID? If you got it, just fill it to the parametes
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"fbID" andDelegate:self];
```

For profile picture, call this url and it will return a jpg link for you

```
http://graph.facebook.com/(username|fbID)/picture
```

Comment: Can I get timeline photos like this ?